# Specman: How to print negative hexadecimals?

Tags: specman

is it possible to print negative hexadecimals in Specman?

For example:

```
var foo : int;
foo = -0x5;
print foo;
```

will print: `foo = 0xfffffffb`.
How can I display the output as `-0x5`?

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a trick as follows:

```
if foo >= 0 then {
    out(foo);
} else {
    out("-", -foo);
};
```

Comment: Actually it prints decimal, but it can be easily fixed: out(appendf(foo = -%x), -foo). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After having a look in the doc, I don't think this is possible. Hex notation is usually used to figure out the bit representation so it doesn't really make sense to show a `-`. If you want to see it in decimal format (regardless of the radix settings), do:

```
print foo using dec;
```

or:

```
print dec(foo);
```